# отправка значения выпадаючого меню на сервер

Tags: ajax, node.js

доброго времени суток. У меня есть выпадающее меню. Возможно ли отправлять значения этого поля на сервер node js? Без отправки формы. Просто при выборе некоторого елемента списка?
HTML-код

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="change" id="changing-input" list="name_list">
    <datalist id="name_list">
      <option id='key' value='key' + onclick="selectPhone(this)"></option>
    </datalist>
    <input type="text" name="" id="changing-input">
    <input type="button" name="" value="Change Phone">
  </form>
```

и примерный Ajax-запрос(как я себе представляю, но не уверен что вообше возможно)

```
function selectPhone(e) {
    console.log(e.value);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            if(!xhr.responseText) {
                document.getElementById('anotherFirm').innerHTML = 'Take another firm';
            }else{
                document.getElementById('changing-input').value = "xhr.responseText";
            }
        }else if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status != 200) {
            console.dir('error');
        }
    };
    // xhr.open('POST', '/registration', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
    var firm = e.value;
    xhr.send(firm);
}
```

Comment: Да, так и должно работать, только `xhr.responseText` без кавычек. И данные формы в `xhr` передать так: var firm = `'firm=' + encodeURIComponent(e.value)`.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev а как тогда принять это на сервере?

Comment: `req.body.firm` + `body-parser`; без вашего серверного кода не могу подсказать точнее

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev я немного не правильно выразился, как обработать именно этот запрос, при отправке фoрмы я обрабатываю `app.post('/...',function());`

Comment: ну все правильно - `app.post('/...',function(req, res){ console.log(req.body.firm) })`, но чтобы у вас появился req.body нужно подключить `body-parser`

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev тоесть на место '/..`. нужно просто поставить названия фукции selectPhone?

Comment: Эмм. Это путь куда вы постите, в вашем примере это `'/registration'`.

Comment: поставив в форму метод пост и действие /registration, ничего не происходит, а это точно возможно, ведь я не отправляем форму

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev отправка на сервер должна произойти без нажатия кнопки, только при выборе елемента списка